# The first time I downloaded doom emacs the doom doctor command is giving errors. What should I do?

Tags: emacs

I am really a beginner and don't understand how a lot of this stuff works. I just installed doom emacs, I've never used emacs before. I ran the doom doctor command and it gives me two warnings.

```
> Checking Doom Emacs...
  ✓ Initialized Doom Emacs 2.0.9
  ✓ Detected 30 modules
  ✓ Detected 118 packages
  > Checking Doom core for irregularities...
    Found font material-design-icons.ttf
    Found font weathericons.ttf
    Found font octicons.ttf
    Found font fontawesome.ttf
    Found font file-icons.ttf
    Found font all-the-icons.ttf
  > Checking for stale elc files in your DOOMDIR...
  > Checking your enabled modules...
> :lang markdown
      ! Couldn't find a markdown compiler, `markdown-preview' won't work
    > :lang sh
      ! Couldn't find shellcheck. Shell script linting will not work

There are 2 warnings!
✓ Finished in 3.7202s
```

What does this even mean? Can I just ignore it? Please bear with me I'm just beginning to learn this stuff. Thanks

Comment: Well it means that the `markdown-preview` command won't work, and that it can't use `shellcheck` to display issues with shell scripts.  You can surely ignore them if they don't sound relevant to you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means Doom can't access those tools since they aren't installed on your system. They aren't necessary, as the warning suggests. If you want both of these utilities, you will need to install [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) for the markdown-preview and [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for shell script linting.

```
npm install -g marked
sudo apt install shellcheck
```

Note that Shellcheck can also be installed from `cabal`, `dnf`, `pkg` or `brew install`.

Afterwards, you should find that running `doom doctor` shows no warnings.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 33, the command is

```
sudo dnf install ShellCheck
```

Please note the capitalization of the characters S and C